# Find sub-string in string

Tags: c

Exists in C method for finding a substring in a string?

If not, how to effectively deal with this problem?

In for cycle? And what is the correct syntax in c?

```
const char subString[] = { "car", "blue", "red"};
char String[] = "I love red color and i hate blue color";

for .... String lenght... {

      printf("I found subString");

}
```

Comment: `const char subString[] = { "car", "blue", "red"};` won't compile, `const char * subString[] = { "car", "blue", "red"};`would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For null terminated C strings:

[strstr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

Comment: Hi, i try to use your strstr, but how can i work with this string?

string = "Madam, I am Adam";
i want find subString = Adam...

thank you

Comment: If you know, that the word of interest is enclosed with spaces, search for `" Adam"` and skip that space afterwards. You might have seen my answers regarding tokenization, but everything has been deleted. You may rephrase your question or add a new question.