# C, work with String

Tags: c, string

i want find subString (from array) in String, but i want find real word.

For example:

```
const char *subString[] = { "adam", "car", "red"};
char* String[] = "madam, I am adam";..
```

And now, how can i find name adam?
But i do not find m **adam** but i want to find just adam...

For example: madam, I am **adam**

How to modifi strstr ?

Can you help me? Thank you..
My last question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883147/find-sub-string-in-string)

Comment: Which compiler complies that `subString`?

Comment: Does not even compile! Try `const char * subString[]`

Comment: You have the same problem with `char * String[]` that should be either `char * String` or `char String[]`.

Comment: Alk: it isnt duplicate,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the following declaration

```
const char subString[] = { ... }
```

you declare that `subString` is an array of characters. You then try to initialize it to an array of strings, which will not work. If you want it to be an array of strings, you have to declare it as an array of pointers to characters:

```
const char *subString[] = { ... }
```

---

As for your problem, one solution is to "tokenize" the string (`String` in your case), i.e. split it on spaces, and then loop over the `subString` array trying to find the string inside the tokenized string.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
for each space-delimited string in String
{
    strip_tokenized_string_of_punctuation();

    for each string in subStrings
    {
        if tokenized_string contains substring
        {
            printf("String contains the word %s\n", substring);
        }
    }
}
```

To help you, you might want to check out the functions [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

Comment: And how i can check effectively? Compare first and last letter from array subString?

Answer (score 0):

There should be the strtok() function, which gets all the words in a string (you have to give a separator as parameter and in your case it is space) you can then iterate all the words that you get and see if they are in your 1st array. then you won't have a problem with "madam", as in your example.